# Python heapq - Python and C implementation? Which one is used?

Tags: python

I am browsing the Python source and noticed a [C implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dcf25060cae8/Modules/_heapqmodule.c) for `heapq`, as well as a [Python implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dcf25060cae8/Lib/heapq.py). Why are there both? Which one is used when I `import heapq` from CPython?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`import heapq` imports the Python implementation. You can confirm that by inspecting the value of `heapq` in the interative interpreter:

```
In [20]: import heapq

In [21]: heapq
Out[21]: <module 'heapq' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/heapq.pyc'>
```

`heapq.pyc` is the byte-compiled version of the `heapq.py` module.

However, [inside the `heapq.py` file](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/dcf25060cae8/Lib/heapq.py#l351) is:

```
# If available, use C implementation
try:
    from _heapq import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

`_heapqmodule.c` provides the `_heapq` module. So if the C implementation is available, `import heapq` uses the C implementation.

Comment: Note that this is a common pattern across a number of performance-sensitive Python libraries.

Comment: I see. In what case would the compiled library be unavailable?

Comment: @Gareth: While CPython is the most commonly used implementation of Python, there are others, such as Jython, IronPython, and PyPy. Some implementations (in particular the Java-based Jython) may use the Python implementation as a base but not the C implementation.

Comment: Besides supporting VM-based Python implementations with no C support, https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-October/083078.html mentions another reason you'll see dual Python/C implementations: the Python version came first, was supplanted by the C version for speed, but kept around for documentation, regression testing, and forkability.

Comment: How can you tell which is actually being used though.? would calling heapq after importing tell you something different?