# Efficient list sorting: Using heap instead of standard sorting is slower

Tags: python, list, performance, sorting, heap

I'm trying to create a more efficient way to sort lists and dictionaries in python and came across [Efficient data structure keeping objects sorted on multiple keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29118602/efficient-data-structure-keeping-objects-sorted-on-multiple-keys). There the suggested solution was to use the [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module.

However, in my tests a heap seems to be twice as slow as the native Python sorting algorithm. Below is the code I used to do a simple test. Results were for example:

> *Heap:* 0.005993366241455078
>
> *Standard:* 0.0020036697387695312

Is there a way to actually use a heap and increase the performance, as the post linked above claims? What would that code look like?

Here's the code to test it:

```
import  random
import time
from heapq import *

standardlist = []
heaplist = []
for i in range(10000):
    num = random.randint(0,10000)
    standardlist.append(num)
    heappush(heaplist, num)

# Standard sorting method:
start_time = time.time()
sorted_list = sorted(standardlist)
finish_time_1 = time.time() - start_time

# Heap sorting method:
start_time = time.time()
heap_sorted_list = [heappop(heaplist) for i in range(len(heaplist))]
finish_time_2 = time.time() - start_time

print("Standard Finish Time:", finish_time_1)
print("Heap Finish Time:", finish_time_2)
```

Comment: Please note that the question you linked is different from your case in that the OP is asking for sorting on multiple keys, and the task is referred to be _add/delete heavy_. None of these conditions seem to reflect your case. Find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749199/when-would-i-want-to-use-a-heap#:~:text=6%20Answers&text=Use%20it%20whenever%20you%20need,the%20largest%20(smallest)%20item.) a good discussion about _heaps_ that might help you in understanding whether they are the right class for the case at your hand.

Comment: Python's TimSort algorithm is extremely efficient, you're wasting your time trying to beat it.

Comment: Heaps are not used for fast sorting, primarily they are used for fast access to max/min value (in O(1) time).

Comment: Inserting items in a heap is cheap (though not so much on binary heaps which are certainly used here). Deleting the min/max item from a heap is the expensive part (`O(log n)` time). If you delete all items, then it will take `O(n log n)` time. Python `sort` use a TimSort which also runs in `O(n log n)` but it is implemented in C, very optimized and TimSort is known to be usually faster than HeapSort. There is no chance you can be faster than `sort` with this code. In fact, with any general-purpose sort written in pure-Python.

Comment: Heap sort only worth it if you want to extract the k min/max items and `k<<n`. In fact, there are faster algorithm in this case too (partitioning can be done in `O(n)` and HeapSort takes `O(n + k log n)` not to mention the higher constant than optimized partitioning algorithms).

Comment: @Luca my use case is to constantly update, add, delete, insert, remove items from the list (at least 60 times per seconds), while keeping it sorted. The above is just a performance test. If sorting a list is faster than merely retrieving the heap as a list, then - even if insertion, deletion, addition are my use case and are faster- it cannot possibly increase performance for what I do.

Comment: So from all the comments I'm learning that heap is only more performant for retrieving min/max values, and retrieving a sorted list will never be more performant in any situation, no matter in which way I use or set up the heap functions, correct? So simply use `sorted` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A heap data structure may be the right solution when you have a collection that changes over time (through insertions and deletions), and at each moment you want to have fast access to the minimum entry that is currently in the collection, and possibly extract it. There were such requirements in the Q&A you linked to.

If however the goal is just to sort a dataset *once*, then using a heap is not the most efficient.

Some remarks on your code:

- The way you have populated the heap has O(log) time complexity. It is more efficient to first populate the list, and then call `heapify` on it: this has a time complexity of O(). Admittedly, this is not relevant for the timings you performed, but it also results in less code:

  ```
  standardlist = [random.randint(0,100000) for _ in range(1000000)]
  heaplist = standardlist[:]
  heapify(heaplist)
  ```
- `sorted` is a native Python function, which can rely on compiled C code for the `sort` part. An explicit loop written in Python cannot beat that.
- Although heapsort has an optimal time complexity, a well-implemented quicksort is [usually 2–3 times faster than heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort#Comparison_with_other_sorts). See also [Quicksort vs heapsort](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2467751/5459839). Python actually [uses a highly optimised sort algorithm](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listsort.txt).
- Your code only performs one test, and it completes in a few milliseconds. This does not give very representative results. It would be better to repeat the test multiple times and get an average.

Comment: `nsmallest` is implemented in pure Python, but the source talks about the complexity of the algorithm used. Loosely speaking, `nsmallest` can be faster because it doesn't necessarily need to maintain the heap property while extracting small values, unlike `heappop`.

Comment: @chepner, I mentioned "possibly through compiled C code", based on the info provided in [Python heapq - Python and C implementation? Which one is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244088/5459839)

Comment: Ah, I missed that because it's waaaay down at the bottom of `heapq.py`. (I should have known better; I was aware that `operator` does the same thing.)

Comment: I did implement the changes you suggested: `nsmallest(len(heaplist), heaplist)` to sort the heap list or apply native `sorted(heaplist)` on the list on which I ran `heapify` before. Both are slower than native sorted (on multiple tests of course). I assume heap is not the right answer in my case to quickly and constantly update and sort lists.

Comment: This is expected as I explained in my answer. There are many situations where you constantly update a collection and still need the collection to remain sorted (maybe not completely?). Depending on the needs there are solutions. You may look into B-trees, AVL trees, red-black trees, skip lists, ...etc. You could benefit from [Python Sorted Containers](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/).

Comment: @trincot thank you very much for the explanation and suggestions. I have created a separate post for the more specific use case, here's the link in case you know more on it and would want to share. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78050551/are-there-faster-ways-to-quickly-modify-update-and-sort-lists-or-dictionaries)

Comment: @chepner What do you mean with `nsmallest` extracting values? Extracting from where? It doesn't modify the given iterable, and it does maintain the heap property of the heap it builds.