# Are there faster ways to quickly modify, update and sort lists or dictionaries?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, sorting, tree

I'm trying to find out if there are faster ways to sort and modify lists in python, other than the native "sorted" function.

***Specific details:***
I have multiple objects from a custom class that I want to sort based on their Z attribute, which is an integer value. Ideally the objects are stored in a dictionary, but a list works as well if it is more performant. They will get updated 60 times per second. And at any frame any Z attribute of any object might change and the list needs to get sorted accordingly. There might be objects added or removed from time to time, but the optimization is oriented especially towards sorting the list/dictionary after an object's Z value changes.

I could also update the list one object or one Z value change at a time and only change that object's position in the sorting, if there is a fast way to do this.

I enquired if [heaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78047552/efficient-list-sorting-using-heap-instead-of-standard-sorting-is-slower?noredirect=1#comment137593084_78047552) would be a good solution for this but they are not.
In that linked post I got suggestions for B-trees, AVL trees, red-black trees, skip lists and Python Sorted Containers, but I'm not sure if they are helpful in my specific use case.

I tried looping a single object through a list until it reaches the correct Z position, but that method is also significantly slower than sorting the entire list using native sorted() command. I pasted the sample code for that test below.

Does anyone know if there are faster more efficient ways of sorting for my specific use case? If so, what would a sample code of a basic implementation be?

Sample code *(this code is merely for performance testing and is not meant to be fully optimized)*:

```
import  random
from statistics import mean
import time


class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Z = random.randint(0,1000000)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.Z)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Z)

# Creating a sorted list first:
list_base = [Object() for i in range(10000)]
sorted_list = sorted(list_base, key = lambda name: name.Z)

# New object that will be added to the beginning of the list with a higher Z value than the others:
new_obj = Object()
new_obj.Z = 1000001

# Store the timing results in lists for performance testing:
results_native = []
results_custom = []

# Run performance test multiple time:
for i in range(200):
    # inserting new object at the beginning of the list:
    # current index:
    index = 0
    sorted_list.insert(index, new_obj)
    # Sort method native:
    start_time = time.time()
    sorted_list = sorted(sorted_list, key = lambda name: name.Z)
    finish_time_1 = time.time() - start_time

    results_native.append(finish_time_1)
    # Inserting the object back to the beginning of the list to repeat the test:
    sorted_list.insert(0, sorted_list.pop(-1))

    # Sort method Custom looping:
    start_time = time.time()
    index += 1
    while not index >= len(sorted_list) and sorted_list[index].Z <= new_obj.Z:
        index += 1
    sorted_list.insert(index - 1, sorted_list.pop(0))
    finish_time_2 = time.time() - start_time

    results_custom.append(finish_time_2)

print("Native finish time:", mean(results_native))
print("Custom loop finish time:", mean(results_custom))
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the list? I.e., what functionality do you need?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I will display the object's images on a surface, it's for a game engine framework, currently with pygame/sdl2. The layer sorting determines which objects are drawn in front/ behind.

Comment: How big are the lists?

Comment: So at each of those 60 times per second, you need to iterate the list once? How many updates happen between two such iterations?

Comment: @JérômeRichard have you ever checked out [`sortedcontainers`](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/)? It doesn't use a b-tree, [the implementation is pretty clever](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/implementation.html) and apparently pretty fast, and written in pure Python.

Comment: @Barmar it is flexible and dependant on the project. 10000 sounds like a good bench mark if I was forced to pick. Obviously more would be cool as well if possible. Let's say 30000 for particle animation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga for my use case I do not think you can sort `sortedcontainers` based off it's item's attributes...

Comment: @Kelly Bundy please elaborate what you mean with an update. Updates per object or how many objects get updated?

Comment: I guess mainly the latter, although the former might be good to know as well.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy an object might be updated from multiple sources which change the attribute, during one iteration. However any changes on the Z attribute will only take effect on the list sorting once per iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and compared bisect and sorted containers.
Here's the median test result for 1000 tests:

```
Native finish time: 0.0036494266986846925
Bisect finish time: 3.2123804092407225e-05
Sorted Container finish time: 1.5070676803588867e-05
```

**Sorted Container lists** have the most performant sorting procedure and therefor I consider the solution for this post!

The code I used for comparing the performance:

```
import numpy as np
import bisect
from sortedcontainers import SortedList


import  random
from statistics import mean
import time

class Object:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Z = random.randint(0,1000000)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.Z)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Z)

# Creating a sorted list first:
list_base = [Object() for i in range(10000)]
container_sorted_list = SortedList(list_base, key=lambda x: x.Z)

# New object that will be added to the beginning of the list with a higher Z value than the others:
new_obj = Object()
new_obj.Z = 1000001

# Store the timing results in lists for performance testing:
results_native = []
bisect_results = []
sorted_container_results = []



print("START PERFORMANCE TEST")
# Run performance test multiple time:
for i in range(1000):
    print(i)

    #NATIVE

    # inserting new object at the beginning of the list:
    # current index:
    sorted_list = sorted(list_base, key=lambda name: name.Z)

    index = 0
    sorted_list.insert(index, new_obj)
    # Sort method native:
    start_time = time.time()
    sorted_list = sorted(sorted_list, key=lambda name: name.Z)
    finish_time_1 = time.time() - start_time
    results_native.append(finish_time_1)

    # BISECT:
    sorted_list_bisect = sorted(list_base, key=lambda name: name.Z)
    start_time = time.time()
    # insert the new value in the correct position
    bisect.insort(sorted_list_bisect, new_obj, key=lambda name: name.Z)
    finish_time = time.time() - start_time
    bisect_results.append(finish_time)

    # Making sure bisect gives the same answer as your native method.
    if not (np.array(sorted_list) == np.array(sorted_list_bisect)).all():
        print("Sorted lists do not match :(")
        raise Exception

    # SORTED CONTAINER:
    start_time = time.time()
    container_sorted_list.add(new_obj)
    finish_time = time.time() - start_time
    sorted_container_results.append(finish_time)
    container_sorted_list.remove(new_obj)

print("Native finish time:", mean(results_native))
print("Bisect finish time:", mean(bisect_results))
print("Sorted Container finish time:", mean(sorted_container_results))
```

Answer (score 2):

Performance matters.
You will scan a sorted list for every displayed frame, at 60 FPS.
You will do K object updates per frame, with K > 1.

There are "incremental" and "sort everything" approaches
to obtaining a sorted list.
Since ten thousand is on the borderline of being a "small"
number, you may be able to get away with batching up K updates
and then sorting everything once per frame, with cost O(N log N).

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList
```

A more attractive approach would be to incrementally
keep the list sorted after each update.
A very nice [implementation](https://pypi.org/project/sortedcontainers) of this idea would be pleased to keep your container always sorted.
For K updates the cost is K × O(log N).
Notice that K << N.

There is also a
[SortedDict](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html)
if you prefer.

Comment: Yeah this library should be the first thing to try when one needs to.maintain a sorted list that is frequently updated

Comment: @J_H the sortedcontainers documentation says nothing about sorting lists and dictionaries based on their item's attributes. Can you give a code sample of how that module can apply to my use case?

Comment: @TrickyDevil Did you overlook its support for a key function?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy Indeed I did overlook it! I implemented the sorted container, as shown in the post below. Sorted Container has the highest performance according to the test.

Comment: @J_H if you include a code snippet of the implementation of sorted container lists, how to create the list and add them item in the performance test, I will mark your answer as the correct answer. (You can just copy paste from the code in the answer I gave below)

Comment: That's fine. I upvoted your answer. Just go ahead and self-accept your own answer. ✅

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to use `bisect`:

```py
import numpy as np 
import bisect
# <your set up code>

# Run performance test multiple time:
for i in range(200):
    # inserting new object at the beginning of the list:
    # current index:
    sorted_list = sorted(list_base, key = lambda name: name.Z)

    index = 0
    sorted_list.insert(index, new_obj)
    # Sort method native:
    start_time = time.time()
    sorted_list = sorted(sorted_list, key = lambda name: name.Z)    
    finish_time_1 = time.time() - start_time
    results_native.append(finish_time_1)

    # Being lazy, just remaking the original list
    sorted_list_bisect = sorted(list_base, key = lambda name: name.Z)
    start_time = time.time()
    # insert the new value in the correct position
    bisect.insort(sorted_list_bisect, new_obj, key=lambda name: name.Z)
    finish_time3 = time.time() - start_time
    bisect_results.append(finish_time3)
    
    # Making sure bisect gives the same answer as your native method. 
    if not (np.array(sorted_list)==np.array(sorted_list_bisect)).all():
        print("Sorted lists do not match :(")
        raise

print("Native finish time:", mean(results_native))
print("bisect" ,mean(bisect_results)) 
# Results for my machine: 
>>> Native finish time: 0.0005652046203613281
>>> bisect 4.755258560180664e-06
```

Here we use the bisect module to insert the new object in the correct position, rather than needing to sort it at each pass, which results in approximately a 100x speed up with your given example.

Comment: Thank you very much for this and the code sample. This is working very well!
Do you happen to know if numba can be used in this use case? Is there a way to apply an njit decorator for example to make it even faster?